# Como coloco un formulario de un modelo extendido en Django

Tags: django

Cree una app en django que se llama empleado

```
class Empleado(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = 'cascade', blank = False)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    sueldo = models.FloatField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 14)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name
```

y quiero juntar el formulario del modelo EMPLEADO con el  modelos User de django por defecto en el mismo template, ¿como seria la vista?, como hago esto, Si me pueden dar un ejemplo de una app completa con algo parecido, lo agradeceria mucho, o si saben resolver el problema, tambien es de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo no es extender, estas relacionando dos tablas (modelos) para que puedas hacer lo que deseas tienes que usar herencia (extender) el modelo de User en Empleado, tu modelos seria el siguiente:

```
class Empleado(User):
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    sueldo = models.FloatField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 14)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.first_name
```

con esto el modelo empleado hereda todos los campos de user,  en el Form bastarías con usar el modelo empleado para acceder a los campos de user también, así:

```
class EmpleadoUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

     class Meta:
         model = Empleado 
         # tienes que usar un fields para especificar que campos se van a mostrar o un exclude para indicar que campos no se van a mostrar
         fields = ['firts_name', 'celula', 'sueldo'] # y demás campos que necesites
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias (y) no se como no lo vi antes

Comment: Pero con esto tambien se heredan los metodos del modelo User??

Comment: Si, se hereda tanto los atributos como las funciones. Te invito a probarlo y me comentas

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es juntar dos formularios puedes hacer uso de un formulario personalizado. ejemplo:

```
from django import forms

class EmpleadoUserForm(forms.Form):
    cedula = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True, error_messages={'required':'El campo célula es obligatorio', 'max_length':'Máximo 11 caracteres'})
    sueldo = forms.FloatField()
    fecha_nacimiento = forms.DateField()
    direccion = forms.CharField(max_length = 80)
    telefono = forms.CharField(max_length = 14)
    ..... y sigue con los datos del usuario
```

Esto crea una clase formulario con los datos de Empleado y Usuario juntos. Si te fijas bien he omitido el campo usuario puesto que si quieres 2 formularios en 1 es con el fin de poder crear un Empleado y un Usuario al mismo tiempo, por lo que sería un error poner el campo para seleccionar un usuario que no existe en ese momento. Con esta clase podrás validar en la función que tengas definida en tu views,py pero no podrás guardar puesto que no existe un objeto real con esos campos. Como te explicaba el objetivo de esta clase es solo validar los datos, una vez valida, inicializas las clases que desees y le llenas los datos con los recogidos en tu formulario. ejemplo

```
from .forms import *
from .models import *

def empleado_create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmpleadoUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      usuario = Usuario(nombre=form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
          .....)
      usuario.save()

      empleado = Empleado( usuario_id = usuario.id,
                           cedula = form.cleaned_data['cedula'],
                           sueldo = form.cleaned_data['sueldo'],
                           fecha_nacimiento = form.cleaned_data['fecha_nacimiento'],
                           direccion = form.cleaned_data['direccion'],
                           telefono = form.cleaned_data['telefono'])
      empleado.save()
      return redirect("Pagina que desees")
  else:
    form = EmpleadoUserForm()
  return render(request, 'pagina del form.html', {'form': form})
```

como ves primero he creado el usuario puesto que la clase empleado debe tener un id de usuario, (ese detalle lo debes tener en cuenta siempre que hagas este tipo de cosas) y al crear el empleado le he pasado como usuario_id el id de usuario creado recientemente. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: bro lo que quiero es extender ese modelo User de django, con ese de empleado, y tener solo un formulario para ambos.por eso coloco la relacion OneToOne.